# eclipse not recognising the default locale

Tags: python, django, eclipse

## doubt

while in terminal i changed the set the LANG=en_US.UTF-8 , LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 , when i generate run python manage.py createsuperuser from the terminal its working , but its not working from the ECLIPSE IDE
why?

## code

```
import locale

print locale.getdefaultlocale()
```

## output

```
(None, None)
```

## error when i run createsuperuser from eclipse

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Abhimanyu/Documents/workspace/new1/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 70, in handle
    default_username = get_default_username()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 105, in get_default_username
    default_username = get_system_username()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 85, in get_system_username
    return getpass.getuser().decode(locale.getdefaultlocale()[1])
TypeError: decode() argument 1 must be string, not None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a great solution, but adding the following two lines to manage.py should get things working. Place them below the call to os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "*PROJECT_NAME*.settings").

```
os.environ["LANG"] = "en_US.UTF-8"
os.environ["LC_ALL"] = "en_US.UTF-8"
```

As for the why part, see [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16017).